# How to decode Kafka messages using Avro and Flink

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-flink

I am trying to read `AVRO` data from a `Kafka` topic using `Flink` 1.0.3.

I just know that this particular Kafka topic is having AVRO encoded message and I am having the AVRO schema file.

> My Flink code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "dojo3xxxxx:9092,dojoxxxxx:9092,dojoxxxxx:9092");
        properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "dojo3xxxxx:2181,dojoxxxxx:2181,dojoxxxxx:2181");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "Zeeshantest");
        AvroDeserializationSchema<Event> avroSchema = new AvroDeserializationSchema<>(Event.class);
        FlinkKafkaConsumer08<Event> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<>("myavrotopic", avroSchema, properties);
        DataStream<Event> messageStream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer);
        messageStream.rebalance().print();
        env.execute("Flink AVRO KAFKA Test");
    }
```

I have created my `Event.java` file using the avro tools and schema "rocana.avsc"

```
java -jar /path/to/avro-tools-1.8.1.jar compile schema rocana.avsc
```

Here is [rocana.avsc](https://github.com/alamzeeshan/CodeShare/blob/master/rocana.avsc) file uploaded in github.

> AvroDeserializationSchema.java

```
import org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.DeserializationSchema;

public class AvroDeserializationSchema<T> implements DeserializationSchema<T> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4330538776656642778L;

    private final Class<T> avroType;
    private transient DatumReader<T> reader;
    private transient BinaryDecoder decoder;

    public AvroDeserializationSchema(Class<T> avroType) {
        this.avroType = avroType;
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(byte[] message) {
        ensureInitialized();
        try {
            decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(message, decoder);
            return reader.read(null, decoder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(T nextElement) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<T> getProducedType() {
        return TypeExtractor.getForClass(avroType);
    }

    private void ensureInitialized() {
        if (reader == null) {
            if (org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase.class.isAssignableFrom(avroType)) {
                reader = new SpecificDatumReader<T>(avroType);
            } else {
                reader = new ReflectDatumReader<T>(avroType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On running my program I am getting the following error:

```
17:25:30,759 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper                                - Session: 0x356350cb9001857 closed
17:25:30,759 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn                               - EventThread shut down
17:25:30,761 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Source: Custom Source (3/4) switched to FAILED with exception.
java.lang.Exception: 2
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.LegacyFetcher.run(LegacyFetcher.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer08.run(FlinkKafkaConsumer08.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:225)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:559)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:402)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:290)
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:267)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:155)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:193)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumReader.readField(ReflectDatumReader.java:230)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:142)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.decode(AvroCoder.java:274)
    at org.fmr.flink.AvroDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroDeserializationSchema.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.KeyedDeserializationSchemaWrapper.deserialize(KeyedDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.LegacyFetcher$SimpleConsumerThread.run(LegacyFetcher.java:657)
17:25:30,769 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Freeing task resources for Source: Custom Source (3/4)
17:25:30,776 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Sink: Unnamed (1/4) switched
```

I think my deserialize code is not correct. Do anyone know what I am doing wrong? Is this the way to read AVRO data from Kafka using Flink or there is a better way around?

Comment: Are you sure that the data in Kafka was encoded with the exact same version of the schema? By creating a `new SpecificDatumReader<T>(avroType)` you are telling the datum reader that `avroType`'s schema is both the reader and writer schema, and I believe you may get these kinds of exceptions if in fact a different version of the schema was originally used to encode the messages.

Comment: Yes, the schema file is the correct one, I used the same `schema file` and `kafka topic` in `logstash` and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever code I posted as per my question works perfectly fine.

Issue was with the data sent to kafka topic, both JSON and AVRO formatted data was sent there. I subscribed to a different Kafka topic where data was only in AVRO and my code worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code to deserialize the Avro record:

```
Schema a; //Your Avro schema
DatumReader<GenericData.Record> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericData.Record>(a);
GenericData.Record a = reader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(bytes, null));
```

Comment: Nope, not working. Same error. Created schema by: `Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("./src/main/resources/rocana.avsc"));`

Comment: This should work if data is just Avro encoded. Can you please check how are you ingesting data into Kafka. If you are using some library then please read the encoder of same.

Comment: Issue was with the data sent to kafka topic, both JSON and AVRO formatted data was sent there. I subscribed to a different Kafka topic where data was only in AVRO and my code worked fine.

Comment: @Zeeshan As you've sorted it out, could you please answer your own question then? Thanks!